Sorting calendar plot with geom_segment() + fix scale
I am trying to do this calendar ggplot2.
So far, it works fine, but I want to make two adjustments, and I am not finding the way:

I want to arrange every segment within each year and num_months, so the first geom_segment that appears in each num_months/box is the first start_month (lower number), then the second start_month (second lower number) and so on...
I want the scale for each year to start in January and end in December despite not having observations.

data <- read_csv("num_months,start_month_year,end_month_year,B1,B1_p,year,start_month,end_month
1,6,6,3.3571016788482666,0.007681768853217363,2021,5,5
1,8,8,2.548985481262207,0.007373321335762739,2021,7,7
1,10,10,2.139772415161133,0.03452971577644348,2021,9,9
1,12,12,2.165775775909424,0.07796278595924377,2021,11,11
1,13,13,1.9506219625473022,0.09215697646141052,2021,12,12
1,23,23,2.7839596271514893,0.011407249607145786,2022,10,10
1,25,25,2.220555543899536,0.06181173026561737,2022,12,12
6,6,11,0.9881601333618164,0.08719704300165176,2021,5,10
6,8,13,1.438501238822937,0.032221969217061996,2021,7,12
6,9,14,1.16400945186615,0.09187468141317368,2021,8,1
6,10,15,1.5834165811538696,0.03494146466255188,2021,9,2
6,11,16,1.294316291809082,0.09792502969503403,2021,10,3
6,12,17,1.4204859733581543,0.0546354204416275,2021,11,4
6,20,25,1.07038414478302,0.0722803920507431,2022,7,12") %>%
  mutate(
    start_dt = case_when(
      year == 2021 ~ ymd(paste("2021", start_month, "01", sep = "-")),
      year == 2022 ~ ymd(paste("2022", start_month, "01", sep = "-"))
    ),
    end_dt = case_when(
      year == 2021 ~ ceiling_date(ymd(paste("2021", end_month, "01", sep = "-")), unit = "month") - 1,
      year == 2022 ~ ceiling_date(ymd(paste("2022", end_month, "01", sep = "-")), unit = "month") - 1,
    ),
    end_month = ifelse(start_month == end_month, end_month + 1, end_month),
    end_month = ifelse(end_month > 12, 1, end_month)  # Wrap around to January if end_month exceeds 12
  ) %>%
  arrange(year, num_months, start_month) %>%  # Sort data within each group by year, num_months, and start_month
  group_by(year, num_months) %>%
  mutate(
    yy = row_number()  # Assign new y position based on sorted order
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

# Create the ggplot

ggplot(data) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = start_dt, xend = end_dt, y = yy, yend = yy, color = factor(num_months)), size = 1) +
  scale_x_date(
    date_labels = "%b",
    date_breaks = "1 month",
    expand = expansion(0, 0)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = NULL) +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(num_months), cols = vars(year), space = "free_y", scales = "free") +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Number of Months", color = "Number of Months") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"), # Increase spacing between panels
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
  )


When I want to show multiple years on the same axis or with the same axis range, I make a version of the variable that is in one year, e.g. data |> mutate(across(start_dt:end_dt,  ~. - years(year(.) - 2000), .names = "{.col}2")).  For your question #1, I'd suggest using tidytext::reorder_within(), but I'm not sure how to implement since you have multiple observations in some facets with the same yy value.

To fix the order make sure that the your start date column actually contains the start date for each event. To this end I added two new columns. Afterwards arrange by the start date before setting yy. To fix the second issue I leverage ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales to set the limits of the scale to include the whole year per facet column:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggh4x)

data <- data |>
  mutate(
    start_dt1 = pmin(start_dt, end_dt),
    end_dt1 = pmax(start_dt, end_dt)
  ) |>
  arrange(start_dt1) |>
  mutate(
    yy = row_number(),
    .by = c(year, num_months)
  )

ggplot(data) +
  geom_segment(aes(
    x = start_dt1, xend = end_dt1,
    y = yy, yend = yy,
    color = factor(num_months)
  ), size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = NULL) +
  facet_grid(
    rows = vars(num_months), cols = vars(year),
    space = "free_y", scales = "free"
  ) +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Number of Months", color = "Number of Months") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"), # Increase spacing between panels
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(
    x = lapply(
      unique(data$year),
      \(x) scale_x_date(
        date_labels = "%b",
        date_breaks = "1 month",
        expand = expansion(0, 0),
        limits = as.Date(paste0(x, c("-01-01", "-12-31")))
      )
    )
  )


